# mongo c++ Bsonbuilder, BSONObj to final c BSON

Tags: mongodb, bson, mongo-c-driver, mongo-cxx-driver

The underlying goal here is read json with arrays sub documents and whatever in string format  `{key:"value", boolkey, true, {subkey: value}, array: [x,y,z] }` and not caring to undertake append_int, append_bool and all that jazz.

any way of using the convenient C++ BSONObj, mongo::fromjson BSONObjBuilder to finally output a C bson_t.

ie. along the lines of either

```
 mongo::BSONObj& query = mongo::fromjson ( szJSON );
 bson_t bson = query.c_obj();
```

or

```
 BSONObj Builder builder;
 ... (build, build, build)

 BSONObj obj = builder.obj();

 bson_t bson = obj.c_obj();
```

given that c++ is built on the c driver one would think that the bson_t is lying within somewhere

Comment: `bson_t` is C API, while `BSONObj` is C++ API. What's the reason to mix them?

Comment: c++ driver is complex, not very stable. c driver is the foundation for many drivers so assume its stable. c bson library on the other hand is awkward to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
bson_t* b = bson_new_from_data(obj.objdata, obj.objsize)
```

but you will always create objects twice.